# unable to send data using jquery ajax with POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

Following is my JQuery Code:

```
$("#ddlMSP").empty().append("<option selected='selected' value='0'>Loading...</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetMSPs.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        data: { UserID: 10},
        dataType: "json",                              
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.length > 0) {
                $("#ddlMSP").empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--select--</option>');
                $.each(response, function () {
                    $("#ddlMSP").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#ddlMSP").empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available</option>');
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("failure");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, txtStatus, errThrown) {
            alert("Error : " + txtStatus + ";" + errThrown);
        }
    });
```

and the below is my asp.net generic handler ProcessRequest method:

```
    Dim MSPs As New ArrayList
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SMT").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "select userid, fname + ' ' + lname AS Name from U " & _
                            "where userid in (select ut1.userid from ut1, ut2 " & _
                                                "where ut1.TID = ut2.TID and ut2.UserID=@UserID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",context.Request.Form(0))
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read
        MSPs.Add(New ListItem(rdr("Name").ToString, rdr("UserID").ToString))
    End While
    rdr.Close()

    cmd.Dispose() : cmd = Nothing
    con.Dispose() : con = Nothing

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Dim JSerializer As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    context.Response.Write(JSerializer.Serialize(MSPs))
```

If I run this code I get the error on context.Request.Form(0). It says index is out of range because there is nothing in Request.Form
This code works if I use JQuery ajax with GET and instead of Request.Form, use Request.QueryString.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong while using jquery ajax with POST?? I have read many questions about jquery ajax but none of their methods worked for me.

Can someone share his/her expertise?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to converts a value to JSON and send it to server.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ UserID: 10})
```